# TypeScript: What property should I use for Element type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to React and TypeScript.

I am getting the following TypeScript error:

```
Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': assignedSlot, attributes, classList, className, and 123 more. ts(2322)
```

I understand I need to specify a property for my Element type, but I don't know which of the 126.

My element looks like:

```
  const lowLevelDefault = lowLevel || (
    <Typography className={classes.typographyStyles} variant="body2">
      <b>Some warning.</b> Some Message
    </Typography>
  );
```

And the error shows up:

```
 let messageText: string | Element = '';

  switch (level) {
    case 'Low':
      messageText = lowLevelDefault;
      break;
```

Would anyone know what property I should use?

Comment: why not define it as React.Node?

Comment: @MatinKajabadi haha I don't know what a React.Node is!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your element is not an `Element` but a `React.ReactNode`.

```
 let messageText: React.ReactNode = '';
```